# How do I prevent a double-click on an Open File dialog from registering a click on the form under it?

Tags: windows, delphi, click, message, double-click

I have a custom control that's essentially a drawing canvas, and a program that uses it for editing files.  When a new file is opened, though, something very strange can happen.

If the user double-clicks on the file in the Open File dialog (standard `TOpenDialog` control) instead of selecting an item and hitting `ENTER`, the canvas underneath registers a click event and ends up executing a draw action at the position of the cursor immediately after loading is complete.

Obviously this is not the intended behavior for this.  I've noticed before that when you double-click the mouse, the double-click message arrives *before* the second click message.  I think the dialog box might be closing from the double-click, and then the second click message arrives and gets sent to whatever's at the appropriate coordinates now that it's gone.

Is there any way I can make this stop happening?  I can't tell my code "after loading, just eat the next click," because it could have been opened with the 'ENTER' key instead, and then it would miss the first legitimate click.  Can anyone think of a better way to handle this?  (Using Windows 7, in case it makes a difference.)

Comment: I guess you want a solution for both dialogs, the XP one, and the Vista one.

Comment: Any chance of a code sample that duplicates? Does not register a click on a form with an empty project.

Comment: I see it consistently, on Windows 7.  (Maybe it's different for different OSes?)

Answer (score 7):

If there's a "second click message," there's something wrong. (For one thing, Windows doesn't have "click" messages, just mouse-up and mouse-down messages.) [A double click goes like this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645601.aspx#_win32_Client_Area_Mouse_Messages): mouse down, mouse up, double click, mouse up. The dialog disappears between the double-click message and the second mouse-up message. If your control receives the mouse-up message and treats it as a full click, then that explains the issue and you need to stop; a click is always a *pair* of mouse-down and mouse-up messages. If you haven't gotten both, then it's not a click.

Comment: The issue does look as if the control is actually catching a mouse-up instead of a click (I mean, as if it is *set* to catch the former rather than the latter).

Comment: perfect! yes, i solved using a flag on method that the Down event fire.
Down event is fired only if picturebox is really cliccked:


        private void pictureBox1_MouseD(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            picturebox_sel_clicked = true;
            Console.WriteLine("D");
        }

Answer (score 1):

In fact, it is The 2nd mouse-up event got fired on the picture box, which leads to the event handler invocation. This seems an OpenFileDialog bug. Need to add check for the IsMouseCaptured for the mouse up event, one click is mouse down and mouse up, instead of only a mouse up.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it that way (it is of course an work-around):

```
    CFileDialog my_file_dialog(...);
    if ( my_file_dialog.DoModal()!=IDOK )
        return;

    CString fileName= my_file_dialog.GetPathName();

    //...

    CSelectItemsDlg dlg;


    // Avoid that the double-click on the CFileDialog sends the WM_LBUTTONUP message to the next window causing the Unselect of an item that is under the mouse cursor.
    // http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/System/Windows__Programming/Q_10287063.html#a2476475
    MSG msg;
    while(PeekMessage(&msg,0,WM_LBUTTONUP,WM_LBUTTONUP,PM_REMOVE));

    int DoModalRes = dlg.DoModal();
```

And you can believe that I have put a big smile on the face of my boss :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Private IsMouseDown As Boolean
Private Sub picNenIn_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles picNenIn.MouseDown
    IsMouseDown = True
    'Code
End Sub
Private Sub picNenIn_MouseMove(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles picNenIn.MouseMove
    If IsMouseDown Then
        'Code
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub picNenIn_MouseUp(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) Handles picNenIn.MouseUp
    IsMouseDown = False
    'Code
End Sub
```